# Running a python command line utility

Tags: python, unix, command-line

So I finished writing a Python program that handles some sample banking info.

I was told to create a makefile for the assignment that will have build,view and clean targets. I've gotten that much done and it works as anticipated.

However, I was told that my instructor would run the program similar to

```
accounts -i
```

where accounts is the program and -i is the arg.

However, I have only been able to use

```
./accounts -i
```

to run the program.

I looked around and I found something about adding the file to PATH but I am really lost as to what I am doing. Is there something wrong on my end or is my instructor telling me to do something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the current directory( . ) to your PATH

Comment: Adding the directory to PATH on your instructor's machine may need another shell script or at least one additional command. I guess that './accounts -i' is the simplest way to run your program. And the instructor may accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add . (the current working directory) to your path with something like (bash/ksh syntax) :

```
export PATH="$PATH:."
```

...but this is widely regarded as a security problem.

You're probably best off just typing ./accounts -i.  Your instructor will probably already know the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would imagine that this was just a simple typo or something like it by your instructor.

In shell scripting, the PATH variables denotes a set of directories (separated by colons) that will be searched for the executable that you are referencing.

So assuming your PATH is equal to ".:/usr/bin", when you type "accounts -i" at the command line, your shell with first search for "./accounts" and then (assuming it does not exist) check for "/usr/bin/accounts".  If it finds either it will then execute the one that exists and pass the given arguments (i.e. "-i").

If you would like to try this out, PATH is generally modified like this:

```
export PATH="directory_name:$PATH"
```

(as it is most likely that you will be wanting to have "directory_name" take precedence over the rest of what is current in $PATH).

However, "." is generally not included in PATH by default, which is considered to be bad practice by many for reasons detailed [here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/dot-path.html).

So my guess is your instructor either has "." in his or her PATH, or will quickly realize that using "./acccounts" is more appropriate.